# What are the alternatives to switch-case statements in C?

Tags: c

Here's my code below:

```
while ( ( c = getopt( argc, argv, "s:E:b:t:vh" ) ) != -1 )
{
  switch ( c )
  {
     case 's':
        params.s = atoi( optarg );
        break;
     case 'E':
        params.E = atoi( optarg );
        break;
     case 'b':
        params.b = atoi( optarg );
        break;
     case 't':
        trace_file = optarg;
        break;
     case 'v':
        verbosity = 1;
        break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need an alternative? What's wrong with the code you posted?

Comment: You could use a series of if else statements or you could lookup a set of values in a table.

Comment: You could use an array of function pointers indexed by the character. But there's really no reason to use anything other than the `switch` statement.

Comment: Again, you need to state what is wrong with your current code and what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But to answer the question, you could use a bunch of if/else statements:

```
while ( ( c = getopt( argc, argv, "s:E:b:t:vh" ) ) != -1 )
{
    if ( c == 's' )
    {
        params.s = atoi( optarg );
    }
    else if ( c == 'E' )
    {
        params.E = atoi( optarg );
    }
    else if ( c == 'b' )
    {
        params.b = atoi( optarg );
    }
    else if ( c == 't' )
    {
        trace_file = optarg;
    }
    else if ( c == 'v' )
    {
        verbosity = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        // always have some kind of default clause
    }
}
```